# VGA passthrough - Code 43 with KVM and libvirt on all AMD hardware

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I've set up a system with an R9-270 and an ATI Rage (PCI graphics card, doesn't use radeon driver) on an FX-8320 and an ASRock 970 Extreme3 R2.0 motherboard with the intention of running Debian Wheezy as host and Windows 8.1 Pro as a guest with the R9 passed through to the guest system. I've followed the guide from the Debian Wiki to do this (https://wiki.debian.org/VGAPassthrough) and have reached the end, but when I boot the guest with the card and its audio device attached I get Code 43 in the guest and the card doesn't work. I've also tested passing it through to an Ubuntu guest which also didn't work.

Apparently it's fairly common to get code 43 errors, but these are mainly with Nvidia GPUs and the only one I've seen for AMD only showed up when that user moved away from an AMD CPU. The guide does not feature any explanation for troubleshooting Code 43 presumably because the author did not get it. I'm running the VM on KVM and passing the card and its audio device through using virt-manager's Add Hardware dialogue. This software configuration is known to work, as this is the same setup used by the author of the above guide.

It seems support for this issue is (understandably) scarce because it isn't commonly used.

EDIT: should probably note that I have blacklisted the radeon driver on the host, and that since it's not in the guide and I can't find a good explanation for how exactly it works I am not using the PCI stub driver.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to come back to this one, but for the sake of future searchers, the solution was to upgrade to a newer kernel from the debian-backports repository. With no other changes upgrading to 3.12 fixed the issue.